# Mocha-Chai Testing: POST tests running twice on Jenkins on Openshift

Tags: jenkins, openshift, mocha.js, mean, chai

Overview of my App:

1. I have an MEAN Stack Application Hosted on OpenShift.
2. A series of test are written in Chai-Mocha Framework which run over Jenkins.
3. I have one test case for POST Api which runs perfectly on local but run twice on server.
4. I am using Xunit for generating test report for Jenkins.
5. The single test for POST Api is executed twice and I get an error that build is failed because, 1 test passes and 1 fails.

Below is my code:

Server.js

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000; //6969;
var services = {},
    config = require('./middleware/api/config')(process.env);

require('./middleware/api')(app, services, config);
console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
var server = app.listen(port, ipaddress); 
module.exports = server;
```

test.js:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var should = chai.should();
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var server = require('../');

chai.use(chaiHttp);
chai.should();

describe("Booking Tests", function(){
    it("A Booking should be made on api/booking/ POST", function(done){
             chai.request(server)
                .post('/api/booking')
                .send({"purpose": "Purpose 4", "startDate": "2016-03-20", "endDate": "2016-03-22", "startTime": "01:30", "endTime": "03:30", "requestor": { "email": "XXX@gmail.com" }, "roomNumber": "111"})
                .end(function(err, res){
                    res.should.have.status(200);
                    res.should.be.json;
                    done();
                })
        });


});
```

test-report:

```
<testsuite name="Mocha Tests" tests="2" failures="1" errors="1" skipped="0" timestamp="Sun, 27 Mar 2016 05:18:21 GMT" time="0.049">
<testcase classname="Booking Tests" name="A Booking should be made on api/booking/ POST" time="0.04"/>
<testcase classname="Booking Tests" name="A Booking should be made on api/booking/ POST" time="0.04"/>
</testsuite>
```

The test - "A Booking should be made on api/booking/ POST" is running twice. In my test file there is only one test but report shows 2 test executed - 1 Passed and 1 Failed.
Please Let me where I am going wrong.

Comment: How are you calling this test from jenkins?

Comment: @DominikGebhart  have written one script in package.json.

npm test = ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --recursive -R xunit test/ > test-reports.xml

So I am calling script in jenkins as npm test.

Comment: Mocha gets 2x a "test finished" information. Either `done()` is called twice, or i.e. some timeout is hit and then `done()` is called. Can you add some debug output so you see if the callback function in `end( ...)` is actually run 2 times? Also, try to disable timeout by adding `this.timeout(0)` just before the `chai.request(...)` line.